# Need Help on Python

Tags: python

I just wrote the code below, and the problem is when I write BANKISGADZARCVA, it still shows a print of WESIERIMUSHAOBA.

```
print("Gamarjoba")
print("tqveni davalebaa ishovot fuli valis gadasaxdelad")
print("Fulis sashovnelad gaqvt ori gza, WESIERIMUSHAOBA da BANKISGADZARCVA")
input('Airchiet Fulis Shovnis Gza: ')
if "WESIERIMUSHAOBA":
print("Sadaa Samushao Am Mtavrobis Xelshi")
elif "BANKISGADZARCVA":
print("Axlobeltan tu ucxostanertad")
```

Comment: Have a look at this tutorial here: http://www.python-course.eu/input.php

Comment: @jwpfox: please make sure to *not **fix*** an error when editing a question...

Answer (score -1):

Python needs indentation. Try this:

```
print("Gamarjoba")
print("tqveni davalebaa ishovot fuli valis gadasaxdelad")
print("Fulis sashovnelad gaqvt ori gza, WESIERIMUSHAOBA da BANKISGADZARCVA")

x = input('Airchiet Fulis Shovnis Gza: ')
if "WESIERIMUSHAOBA" in x:
    print("Sadaa Samushao Am Mtavrobis Xelshi")
elif "BANKISGADZARCVA":
    print("Axlobeltan tu ucxostanertad")
```

More, there's no need for so many prints. You could compress them as follows:

```
print('Gamarjoba\n'
      'tqveni davalebaa ishovot fuli valis gadasaxdelad\n'
      'Fulis sashovnelad gaqvt ori gza, WESIERIMUSHAOBA da BANKISGADZARCVA\n')

x = input('Airchiet Fulis Shovnis Gza: ')
if "WESIERIMUSHAOBA" in x:
    print("Sadaa Samushao Am Mtavrobis Xelshi")
elif "BANKISGADZARCVA":
    print("Axlobeltan tu ucxostanertad")
```

In PEP8 (which is what every Python developer should read) it's written that:

Use 4 spaces per indentation level.

> Continuation lines should align wrapped elements either vertically
>   using Python's implicit line joining inside parentheses, brackets and
>   braces, or using a hanging indent. When using a hanging indent
>   the following should be considered; there should be no arguments on
>   the first line and further indentation should be used to clearly
>   distinguish itself as a continuation line.

Comment: Don't forget to press the green check mark if this answer helped you, @SabaKhukhunashvili,

Comment: Python needs indentation! Right. But where did he get it wrong? The problem was completely different.

Comment: The problem is not the indentation. The problem was failure to use variables correctly and to create if tests that do what the OP intended them to do. Only after all those errors are out of the way does the indentation problem even begin to matter. And yet you devote your answer to that trivia instead of the major issues that arises before that.